# Load 93-2003 Excel Worksheet (.XLS) into Excel R

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to load excel worksheets into R using the xlsx package. The files are saved as old 97-2003 worksheets (the endings are .XLS) for newer files the code below worked fine.

```
df <- read.xlsx(filename,sheetIndex=2)
```

However, when I try on the older files I get the error message:

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.apache.poi.hssf.OldExcelFormatException: The supplied spreadsheet seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8 format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)

I know the error has to do with the files being in the older format but I do not know how to solve this. I have too many files to manually update each one. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. apologies for not adding a fully reproducible example. I do not know how to attach files to go along with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `readxl` is one way to read Excel files. The advantage is that there is no dependy to Java or other.

Your code would be

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel(path = filepath, sheet =2)
```

It should work with XLS and XLSX files.

Use `excel_sheets(filepath)` to get the name of sheets to import and pass them through the `sheet` arg of `read_excel`. You can do a loop with that if it helps you.